# Understanding illustrations of topologies in Munkres

Tags: general-topology

The description of the following illustration in Munkres reads:

One can now see that the collection $\mathscr{B}$ of all circular regions in the plane generates the same topology as the collection $\mathscr{B}'$ of all rectangular regions.

[image]

Can someone please elaborate on the meaning of this illustration? I may just be oblivious, but I'm not understanding the relation between the caption and the image. Also, how does this relate to bases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The figure is referring to the preceding lemma, which states that the topology generated by basis $\mathcal{B}'$ is finer than (larger than) the topology generated by basis $\mathcal{B}$, if and only if for each $x \in X$ and $B \in \mathcal{B}$ containing $x$ there exists $B' \in \mathcal{B}'$ such that $x \in B' \subseteq B$.

The image on the right shows that for any circle $B$ containing $x$, you can fit a rectangle $B'$ inside $B$ that contains $x$. The image on the left shows that the same holds with the roles of the bases reversed. Thus each topology is finer than the other, so they are the same.

Comment: Why must $B' \subseteq B$ in the last part of the lemma?

Comment: Am I correct in saying that $B' \subseteq B$ because $B$ is an open set in $T'$, which therefore implies that all base elements in $\mathcal{B}$ must be subsets of members of the topology $T'$?

Answer (score 0):

$\mathscr B$ is the base for a topology $T$ and $\mathscr B'$ is the base for a topology $T'.$

Each  $B\in \mathscr B$  is equal to $\cup F$  for some  $F\subset \mathscr B',$ so each $B\in T'.$ So $\mathscr B\subset T'.$

Each $t\in T$ is equal to $\cup G$ for some   $G\subset \mathscr B,$ and since $\mathscr B\subset T',$ we have  $G\subset T'$ so $t=\cup G\in T'.$ Therefore $T\subset T'.$

Interchanging the primed and un-primed superscripts we also get $T'\subset T$.

One of the pictures is showing that whenever $p\in B\in \mathscr B$ there exists $B'\in \mathscr B$ such that $p\in B'\subset B.$ So for each $p\in B$ we may  take $B'_p\in \mathscr B'$ such that $p\in B'_p\subset B.$ Then $$B=\cup \{\{p\}:p\in B\}\subset \cup \{B'_p: p\in B\} \subset B$$ so $B=\cup F$ where $F=\{B'_p:p\in B\}\in T'.$